# Change the CSS when there is a required element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a student developer and I'd like to make a message appear when I click on the submit button but there's still a select required

```
<style>
    .messagerequire {
        color: red;
        display: none;
    }
</style> 

<p class="messagerequire">Test, If there is a require to submit I appear ! </p>
```

Here it has the style `display:none` and I thought I would do that if the form doesn't validate because of a requirement, it changes the CSS.

I've been searching since this morning for answers, but I haven't found or understood.

`<input type="submit" name="register" value="register">`

Thanks you

Comment: How is this related to `php`? Can you post the jquery that toggles the display/handles form submission?

Comment: Hope this will help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation. The examples on the page are simple and well explained. You can read and try.

Comment: My php shows a lot of options with selects that are required or not and if you don't click at least one option you can't submit. 
Now I would like that a JS/jQuery fonction if we press the submit button and there is a required one, it displays a message

(I haven't yet jQuery that toggles the display/handles form submission)

Comment: I'll read, thank you ! @jim1427

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if the select input is invalid in your submit handler, then change the display property for that `p` element (in this case the first element that has the class). Not the most elegant solution but the simplest in your case:

```js
var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit');

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('messagerequire')[0].style.display = 'block';
})
```

```html
<style>
    .messagerequire {
        color: red;
        display: none;
    }
</style> 

<p class="messagerequire">Test, If there is a require to submit I appear !</p>

<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

A better approach in my view would be to have two classes for showing and hiding the error and dynamically toggling the `p` elements' class instead of modifying it's styles.

Answer (score 0):

you code should be something like below. becuase you are using input type=submit so before submit it should validate.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    document.getElementById('error').style.display='block';
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<style>
    .messagerequire {
        color: red;
        display: none;
    }
</style> 
<form name="myForm" action="/page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<p class="messagerequire" id='error'>Test, If there is a require to submit I appear ! </p>
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I need to do this with a `<select required="" type="text" name="fname" multiple>                 <option>A</option><option>B</option></select></div>` And not an <input....

Do you know how can i do pls ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript to achieve this.

```js
function submitThis(){
  let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  
  if(name.length === 0){
    document.getElementsByClassName("error")[0].innerText = "Cannot leve name empty.";
    //Removing(hinding) the error after 5 seconds.
    setTimeout(()=>{
    document.getElementsByClassName("error")[0].innerText = "";
    }, 5000);
  }
    

}
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" palceholder="Name" id="name" required />
<br>
<br>
<p class="error"></p>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="submitThis()">SUBMIT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please you try it.

```js
 $('#submit').click(function(){
    $('.messagerequire').css('display','block');
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .messagerequire {
            color: red;
            display: none;
        }
    </style> 
<body>
    <p class="messagerequire">Test, If there is a require to submit I appear !</p>

    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</body>
```